# Editing PDF document online and save in the database using ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, pdf, pdf-viewer

I have a PDF document storted as binary in the SQL Server database. I have rendered the binary document as PDF inside an iFrame using HTTP Handler.

Now, I want to allow the users to edit the data in the PDF file shown inside the iFrame and also populate some of the fields in the PDF automatically on clicking a button.

After all the fields are populated, the filled PDF document in the iFrame should be saved back as binary in the database.

How can this be implemented using ASP.NET 4.0?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for http://www.radpdf.com/

Comment: I tried this component. It meets all my needs except digital signature. This doesn't support signature at this moment.

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented this by adding HTTP Submit button inside the Adobe Acrobat (interactive) form. When the submit button is clicked, the PDF document will be posted to the server (an ASPX page). ASPX page will read the PDF document posted as stream, convert that into bytes and store in the database.

Comment: This will only work if your clients have Adobe Acrobat Standard or Professional installed. If they have Adobe Reader, only FDF and XFDF can be submitting via HTTP (PDF won't be). See: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/acrobat/pro/using/WS58a04a822e3e50102bd615109794195ff-7dd6.w.html

Comment: No, you can submit the PDF even if the client doesn't have Adobe Acrobat. I have tried this with only Adobe Reader and it worked fine.

Comment: Are you sure? The documentation I linked to is pretty clear "Note: If the users that fill in the PDF form are using Adobe Reader, you must choose either FDF or XFDF for the Export Format option.", ref: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/acrobat/pro/using/WS58a04a822e3e50102bd615109794195ff-7dd6.w.html

Comment: @Anand can you provide/share your code here, I am searching exactly like this and will helpful to me.

Answer (score 0):

This is the difficult part of your question:

> Now, I want to allow the users to edit the data in the PDF file shown inside the iFrame and also populate some of the fields in the PDF automatically on clicking a button.

You're going to need a third party tool that provides an API for filling form fields in a PDF. There are a few cheap ones and a few expensive ones. The only ones I've ever used successfully are

- [activePDF](http://www.activepdf.com/products/serverproducts/toolkit/)
- [Aspose](http://www.aspose.com/documentation/.net-components/aspose.pdf.kit-for-.net/how-to-fill-form-fields-with-api.html)

But there is also some open source projects:

- [iText](http://itextpdf.com/) ("iTextSharp") ([example](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb/CompleteFormFieldsOfPDFs.aspx))

These tools can be used to fill in the fields of a PDF, as well as for other *basic* edits to PDFs, but things like editing text outside of form fields is very tough to do. There are entire software suites built around PDF authoring (think Adobe Acrobat). They should all provide ways to give you the new PDF (as a file, a byte array, a stream) so you can persist it back to the database.

You might have better luck allowing users to download and edit Word documents (or whatever equivalent you choose) and converting the end result into PDF. Aspose again could help with filling form fields in a document as well as the conversion from Doc to PDF.

I am not affiliated with Aspose in any way -- it just seems to be the tool of the trade for these sort of tasks.

Comment: I had a look at activePDF, Aspose and iText. They provide ability to fill the form fields on the PDF but they do not provide the ability to display the PDF in the web page and get user's inputs and then save the file in the database. I found one tool RADPDF to be very useful and meet all my needs except digitally signing the PDF document.